# Double-sized checkbox in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

All browsers except Chrome do display this style:

```
.my-checkbox {
    width: 20px;
    height:20px;
    color:#fff;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    -o-appearance:none;
    border: 0px inset ThreeDFace ! important;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sJxst/

is this approach possible in Chrome?

Comment: Never knew something like that, will be useful for making big checkboxes which will match windows 8 big texts :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a jquery plugin for this.. i don't know any other method yet for Chrome

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/ui-checkbox

Also check this:

```
input.checkbox { display: none }
input.checkbox + label > span.checkbox-span { display: inline-block; color: #FFF; border: 1px solid #000; width: 30px; line-height: 30px; font-size: 24px; text-align: center }
input.checkbox:checked + label > span.checkbox-span { color: #000 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KfjuS/4/

Comment: demo page of that plugin has "With jQuery UI checkbox" pane and "Native widgets", which are the same =)

Comment: yes, thanks. I should think in way of spans styles as checkbox marks. great idea!

Comment: You can select my answer if satisfied :)

Comment: The link is now broken.